# LoadPackagedLibrary failes with ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND on XBox

Tags: c++, dll, uwp, dllimport, xbox

i'm currently trying to load a self-written dynamic link module (Compiled with `/ZW /EHsc`) in an UWP app using the `LoadPackagedLibrary(...)` function. It is required to load all libraries dynamically due to the way the libs are build. I have included the DLL within the project and enabled it as content (Also verified: it at least gets copied to the XBox like expected).

In case I run my application on Windows everything works fine as expected. But as soon as I launch my application on the XBox `LoadPackagedLibrary(...)` failed with `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND`. In the Visual Studio output window, I can see that the XBox is loading my DLL with no problems but directly discards it after loading it:

```
"DAServerUWP.exe" (Win32): "D:\DevelopmentFiles\<<MYAPP>>\SampleDAClient.dll" geladen. Symbole wurden geladen.
"DAServerUWP.exe" (Win32): "D:\DevelopmentFiles\<<MYAPP>>\SampleDAClient.dll" wurde entladen.
```

I suspect it has something to do with the `Package.appxmanifest` not properly (or currently not at all) specifying the DLL. But I didn’t find that much information online nor did any of the proposed solutions work.

Edit: Here are the lines how the DLL is defined in the `.vcxproj`:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
   <None Include="SampleDAClient.dll">
      <DeploymentContent>true</DeploymentContent>
   </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Edit2: Probably it has something to do with dll dependencys. Theses are my libs dependencys:

[image: Desktop_To_UWP_dll]

which look totaly different when compared to an native UWP dll:

[image: Native_UWP_dll]

Comment: Has the dll file that added to your project been set to `content` type?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Yes, I have selected `True` for `Content` in VisualStudio. However, inside the `.vcxproj` file the dll is under the `None` xml Tag with `DeploymentContent` equal to `true`. I have included the lines regarding the dll in the original question.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I think I have isolated the problem: There has to be an module dependency inside my DLL that is not availible on XBOX. When comparing to the native UWP dll, it used a completly diffrent naming pattern and a special runntime (VCRUNTIME_XXX_APP). I will add the screenshots to the question. But I need to get an desktop cross plaform dynamic link lib running on XBOX because the used build system (premake) does not support UWP / Windows Store apps. The only thing it allowes me to do is add special flags to the linker and compiler (And I tried to match these).

Comment: I asked other engineers and they told me the same thing - the DLL is probably missing a dependency that is present on other platforms, but not Xbox.  Our suggestion is that you might need to find other dlls that support Xbox instead of using these dlls.

Comment: Is there no way to change the project type by adding a compiler argument? My DLL itself works fine when migrated to a Universal Windows project. So the problem is not the features used by the DLL.

Comment: Now after converting the project to UWP the DLL is not usable on windows desktop. Why is it not possible to set the project type on a per platform base?

Comment: Not sure why the DLL is designed to be like this. I think you might submit feedbacks for this issue in the Feedback Hub. Currently, you still need to use other DLLs that supported on Xbox

Comment: I'm currently writing a little tool that copies and converts the `.sln` and '.vcxproj' files to a separate directory just for building the UWP dlls. I will take the time later and submit a feedback when I'm done with the tool and know exactly what it takes to go this dual support rout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compile a UWP DLL you need to pass these arguments to the compiler:

```
/D__WRL_NO_DEFAULT_LIB__ /DWINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_APP /MD
```

And these linker flags:

```
/APPCONTAINER /NODEFAULTLIB:ole32.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:kernel32.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:user32.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib windowsapp.lib
```

Furthermore, you need to specify a different LIBPATH to the linker. Instead of this:

```
/LIBPATH:<VSDIR>\VC\Tools\MSVC\<MSVC_VERSION>\lib\x64
```

You need to use pass this LIBPATH to the linker:

```
/LIBPATH:<VSDIR>\VC\Tools\MSVC\<MSVC_VERSION>\lib\x64\store
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Works fine. Finally a working solution to unify UWP and Desktop development in one vs solution. Now I can continue blaming the series s/x retail dev kits for not reporting all DirectX 12 features they are capable of in UWP mode :-) I hope Microsoft will at some point of time allow everybody to develope for the XBOX with the free GDK… It would solve all that UWP madness once and for ever.

Comment: The details in [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/directx-and-uwp-on-xbox-one/) about *UWP on Xbox* applies to both Xbox One and Xbox Series X|S. It is true that there's no 'enhanced' GPU features exposed through UWP on Xbox for Xbox Series X|S as it just exposes Direct3D Hardware Feature 11.0.